# ASP.net and making a method async

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, lucene

I am attempting to make an ASP.net method that performs a Lucene search asynchronous.  Lucene.NET does not have any built in async/await implementation (that I could find) so I thought maybe I would look into how to enhance my normal synchronous method and make it asynchronous.

```
public ActionResult Search(string queryText, int page = 1, int size = 10)
{
    List<object> matches = new List<object>();
    // a bunch of IO based Lucene stuff here
    // DON'T USE Task.Run()... it is bad in ASP.net
    return Json(matches, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

What is the best strategy for doing this in an ASP.net world?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: are you going to fire and forget and get callback via SignalR or something else or do you need to wait in the same request ?

Comment: If the operation isn't asynchronous then there's nothing you can magically do to make it asynchronous. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be requiring async with Lucene, you should be updating your Lucene index in another background job and the read from your application on the Lucene index should not require an async call.

Comment: @charlesmager I am attempting (and probably wrongfully so) to proactively make everything everything as efficient as possible.  Since the Lucene query is essentially an IO operation, my thinking was if it was possible to somehow make the calls I am using async, that would be ideal.  Basically I was looking to make use of async/await somehow...

Comment: @nokturnal Lucene would have to do that. There's nothing you can do after-the-fact to make Lucene's IO operations asynchronous.

Comment: @charlesmager amazing, thanks for the info.  Maybe my google'ing skills were lacking today, but I found it difficult to get that definitive answer on the net.  In my mind I also thought there had to be a way to make use of async/await/tasks somehow to accomplish what I wanted... clearly that is not the case :)

Answer (score 1):

Visit This [Link](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).It's helpful..

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).